# Images load quicker in webview

Tags: android, image, caching, webview, download

So on my android app, it uses webview to connect to my website and display the index.php file that is on there. That file takes images from a directory on my website and displays them. The problem is that it takes forever for the images to download onto the app! Is there a way I could get the images pre-loaded into the application so that it still runs the PHP like it is supposed to but it doesn't download the images from my website? The images would have the same name and everything. Think of it as having the images cached before downloading them. Is there anyway to do that?